# spring boot guavaCacheManager cacheName-cache

Tags: spring-boot

This is the spring boot source code:

```
/**
 * Create a native Guava Cache instance for the specified cache name.
 * @param name the name of the cache
 * @return the native Guava Cache instance
 */
protected com.google.common.cache.Cache<Object, Object> createNativeGuavaCache(String name) {
    if (this.cacheLoader != null) {
        return this.cacheBuilder.build(this.cacheLoader);
    }
    else {
        return this.cacheBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

all the name of cache  **only one cache** 
How do I create two different caches???

Comment: sorry,here is my problem：I want to create an expire cache and a non-expire chache

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple GuavaCache with different `expiry time` in spring like this :

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    private static final int TIME_TO_LEAVE = 120;                //in minutes
    private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 100;

    public static final String CACHE1 = "cache1";
    public static final String CACHE2 = "cache2";

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();

        GuavaCache cache1 = new GuavaCache(CACHE1,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(TIME_TO_LEAVE, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .maximumSize(CACHE_SIZE)
                        .build());

        GuavaCache cache2 = new GuavaCache(CACHE2,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(TIME_TO_LEAVE, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .maximumSize(CACHE_SIZE)
                        .build());


        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(cache1, cache2));

        return simpleCacheManager;
    }
}
```

You can access these cache by simply annotating a method with `Cacheable` annotation and providing cache name as `value` :

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConfiguration.CACHE1)
int getAge(Person person){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is exactly for you, but you create caches using the [getCache(String)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCacheManager.html#getCache-java.lang.String-) method. You can create as many as you want.